# C++ Calling a superclass function of the same virtual function

Tags: c++, inheritance, subclass, pure-virtual

I'm relatively new to c++ so I'm getting used to the scope of functions and variables in this environment. One issue I can't solve is being able to call a function defined in a subclass of a class which declares this function as pure virtual. Here's my class structure:

```
class Clock{

    public:
        virtual void Tick() = 0;
        std::string Print();

        //Mutators
        int Seconds();
        int Minutes();
        int Hours();
        void setTime(int secs, int mins, int hours);

        //Accessors
        int getSecs(){ return _secs; }
        int getMins(){ return _mins; }
        int getHrs(){ return _hours; }
    private:
        int _secs, _mins, _hours, _days = 0;
    };

    class NormalClock : public Clock{

    public:
        void Clock::Tick();
    private:
    };

    class AlarmClock : public Clock{

    public:
        void Clock::Tick();
        bool CheckAlarm();
        void SetAlarmTime(int hrs, int mins, int secs);
        int GetAHrs();
        int GetAMins();
        int GetASecs();
    private:
        int _alarmhrs, _alarmmins, _alarmsecs;
    };
```

In my source file I want to define a body for the `Tick()` function in the `AlarmClock` class. But within this function I want to call the `Tick()` function from it's superclass, the `NormalClock` class. My issue is that when I do so without defining any objects to work off of, I can't call the superclass `Tick()` function as my IDE (VS2013) thinks I'm referring to the `Tick()`from the current class (the `AlarmClock` subclass). I looked around on the web and determined that it would probably require the use of the `using` keyword, but I've been unsuccessful in implementing it properly. Here's the function I'm trying to build for reference:

```
void AlarmClock::Tick(){

    NormalClock::Clock::Tick();

    if (this->CheckAlarm()){ cout << "\nAlarm! @ " << this->Print() << "\n\n"; }
}
```

There's no errors in VS when calling the function as above, but the compiler complains of a static reference to a non-static member, which is understandable.

Comment: `AlarmClock` is not inheriting from `NormalClock` and so cant use the scoping rules, because they are not really related in the correct way. If `AlarmClock` *did* inherit from `NormalClock` you could simply do e.g. `NormalClock::Tick();`

Comment: In C++, a 'superclass' is usually called a 'base class'.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You were close, but your code has a few problems.

1. AlarmClock does not inherit from NormalClock
2. In AlarmClock::Tick call NormalClock::Tick() instead of NormalClock::Clock::Tick()
3. In NormalClock change Clock::Tick to Tick in your class declaration.

Answer (score 0):

`AlarmClock` does not derive from `NormalClock` so you are calling the method statically (there is no instance of `NormalClock` to be used).

Answer (score 0):

```
    NormalClock::Clock::Tick();
```

looks a lot like you mean the right thing. Now make your `AlarmClock` actually inherit from `NormalClock`, and then just `NormalClock::Tick()` away :)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone, looks like it was a simple case of changing the base class declaration to `NormalClock`in the definition of the class `AlarmClock`. VS2013 was skipping over the `NormalClock` class and observing only the `Tick()` pure virtual function in `Clock`, which is why I couldn't call `NormalClock::Tick()` as intended in the body of the `AlarmClock::Tick()` function.